# Console.log internet explorer 11 [object Object]

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, console

It is possible to log object in internet explorer 11? When I try to log it the output is `[object Object]`and it's not possible to know the content of this variable. Every time I must switch to chorme or firefox only to check the content, but I can't develop in chrome because the main browser of our applications is internet explorer

Comment: When I log an object with console.log in javascript in the console I see `[object object]` instead of the content...

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/56R7d/, in IE11 I only see the `[object Object]` in the console, but in chrome I see the structure...

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/wJ9kwJ5.gif) is what I see in IE11...

Comment: and [this](http://i.imgur.com/7NkNfUg.gif) is what I see in my IE11

Comment: Hmm... In the above linked MSDN article they say "`New in Windows 8.1 ... more intelligent logging ... console.log(), the div element is displayed as an inspectable DOM node...`". When using Win7 you should probably use `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`. I'm running IE11 with Win7 though... Have you updated to the latest version of IE (11.0.9600.17041)?

Comment: Yes, I have the last version. If I use `console.dir()` it works well and I can see the content! Many thanks man!

Comment: @Teemu: It seems that, as described on the page you linked to, the solution for older Windows versions is indeed to use `console.dir()`. Could you please post that as a proper answer to this question?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Well, I'm not sure about the details, IE console has been updated several times after this question. Currently I'm getting an abstract of an element's outer HTML, when logging a HTMLElement, (Win7 + IE11), dir will give a tree though. I'd recall that I didn't give answer, because of the conflict between OP's and my IE behavior.